# angular2 error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: angular

In Angular2 my getting problem to load internal ts file.
inside main.ts i am calling app.component.

Errors are
**Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)**

**Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:12228/app/app.component(…)**

**http://localhost:12228/node_modules/angular2/platform/browser Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)**

```js
Main.ts

import {bootstrap} from '../node_modules/angular2/platform/browser';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);

app.component.ts

import {Component} from '../node_modules/angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'hello-world',
    template: '<h1>Hello World From www.angulartypescript.com</h1><h2>Hallo</h2>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

```html
Index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Login</title>
 


    <!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>-->

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.8/angular2.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/http.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/router.dev.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-localstorage.js/1.0/backbone.localStorage-min.js"></script>


    <script>
        System.config({
            map: {
                app: 'assets/js/app'
            },
            packages: {
                app: {
                    defaultExtension: 'js',
                    format: 'register'
                }
            }
        });
        System.import('app/main').then(null, console.error.bind(console));



    </script>


    <!--<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.min.js"></script>-->
    <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
    
</head>
<!-- Run the application -->
<body>
    <h1>Angular 2 Form builder </h1>
    <hello-world>Loading Sample...</hello-world>

</body>
</html>
```

Please suggest me how to solve this.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'; // <----
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

and

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core'; // <----

@Component({
  selector: 'hello-world',
  template: '<h1>Hello World From www.angulartypescript.com</h1><h2>Hallo</h2>'
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

because these modules are explicitly registered by the files you import (`https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.9/angular2.min.js`)

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the similar problem. After spending about 3 hours, I realized I was running the `ng serve` command in wrong directory.

Just check your present working directory before starting the angular project.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your application in Visual Studio change the

```
import {AppComponent }  from './app.component'
```

to

```
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component.js'
```

Also change the file extension to *.js*. and make sure that your file "URL" points to 
the file.